# How to get email, name and date out of the string with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have this string

```
> Begin forwarded message:
>
> From: "Gardner, Sharon" <some@email.com>
> Date: 10 November 2015 at 21:10:25 GMT 
> *Originla message text*
```

I need to capture email, name and date out of it

---

Tried this:

- to capture the email `preg_match('/\<(.*)\>/', $this->inbound->TextBody(), $email);`
- to capture name `preg_match('/From: "(.*)"/', $this->inbound->TextBody(), $name);`
- and Date: `preg_match('/Date: (.*)\n/', $this->inbound->TextBody(), $name)`

This does the job, but I'm unsure if this reliable?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: and.... ? another homework problem?

Comment: You may need to review [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question.

Comment: better to make your first two patterns un[greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) `.*?` and no need to escape `<` `>`

Comment: @bobblebubble thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're *much* better off ignoring regex completely if you can do simple string processing instead. An email is [notoriously hard](http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) to create a regex for.

So far, if you've got a consistent pattern, it looks like you can find the lines with `From:` and `Date:` and parse the rest of the line appropriately. PHP has a [decent set of functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) to split and manipulate strings, so try that first.